# How to set icon on top of Android Wear card

Tags: android, wear-os, android-cardview, android-cards

How in Android Wear app set icon on top of card like on picture below (green icon)

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: downvoating because this is the app icon in the default way notifications look on android wear - http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#notifications_on_android_wear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [setContentIcon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#setContentIcon(int)) from the `WearableExtender`

From the doc

> Set an icon that goes with the content of this notification.